# Wrapping Asynchronous NPM in Meteor

Tags: meteor, npm

I am using meteor-npm to use NPM in my Meteor app. I have successfully added serialport and xbee-api. I can read xbee frames using console.log, but I cannot pass the frame to a Meteor method. The code below gives me an error about NPM functions and using bindEnvironment. I'm sure that it has something to do with Meteor running synchronous vs xbee-api running asynchronous. I'm fairly familiar with Meteor, but not with using it with NPM. I believe the answer may be in https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm. I don't really need a callback, as I just want the frame data passed to a method and I will handle it from there. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks in advance.

```js
// Load serialport and xbee-api
var serialport = Meteor.require('serialport');
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var xbee_api = Meteor.require('xbee-api');

// Load constants to help with remembering hex codes for xbees
var C = xbee_api.constants;

// Create xbee
var xbee = new xbee_api.XBeeAPI({
    api_mode: 2
});

// Create serial port
var serialPort = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbserial-A901L66E', {
    baudrate: 9600,
    // Provided with xbee-api. Could use com.parsers.raw and feed that to xbee-api
    parser: xbee.rawParser()
});

// Setup action to take when serial port is connected
serialPort.on('open',function() {
  console.log('Port open');
});

// Setup action to take when xbee packet is received
// frame_object is emitted by the xbee.rawParser every time a complete xbee packets is    received
xbee.on('frame_object', function(frame) {
    //Send frame to Meteor method
    Meteor.call('xbeeIncoming', frame);
    //console.log('>>',frame);
});
```

Meteor method definition:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    xbeeIncoming: function xbeeIncoming(frame) {
        console.log('xbeeData');
        //var xbeeSenderAddr = frame.addr
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a method to do this. If both of them are on the server side you could use a private method instead i.e

```
xbeeIncoming = function(frame) {
    console.log('xbeeData');
}
```

instead of `Meteor.call('xbeeIncoming', frame);` you could use `xbeeIncoming(frame);`

You will need to wrap the callback from xbee in a bindEnvironment (provide it can be serialized into JSON/EJSON):

```
var onFrame = function(frame ) {
    Meteor.call('xbeeIncoming', frame);
    //console.log('>>',frame);
}

xbee.on('frame_object', Meteor.bindEnvironment(onFrame));
```

From within this, `Meteor.call` should work as expected

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was able to simply use a "private method" and avoid Meteor.bindEnvironment entirely.